# Combining vectors by index

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I am looking to write a function which inputs two vectors of length n,

i.e. [:a :b :c :d :e :f] [1 2 3 4 5 6]. 
Outputting one vector of length 2n

[:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6].

However, if the second vector being input doesn't match the length of n it will cycle,

i.e. [:a :b :c :d :e :f] [1 2 3]

outputs: [:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 1 :e 2 :f 3].

```
 (defn Swanson [x y] (vec (flatten (interleave x (repeat (count x) y)))))
```

Moreover, the function can also take [x y min max n], where x and y are vectors, min is an index to start the interleaving, max is an index to end the interleaving, and n is a step-size for the interleaving.

Comment: I'd say the min/max/n arguments don't belong in this function - they add too many unrelated responsibilities. Instead, use a simple version of this function with just x/y, and combine take, drop, and take-nth (or something - I haven't worked through the details). Then if you want, you can build another function that takes all five args and calls the four relevant functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With x and y vectors, min the (inclusive) starting index, max the (exclusive) ending index, n the step size:

```
(defn swanson [x y min max n]
  (->> (interleave x (cycle y))
       (take max)
       (drop min)
       (take-nth n)))
```

Answer (score 6):

You want `cycle`:

```
user> (take 6 (cycle [1 2 3]))
(1 2 3 1 2 3)

user> (interleave [:a :b :c :d :e :f] (cycle [1 2 3]))
(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 1 :e 2 :f 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the interleave function from the seq library for that:

```
=> (interleave [:a :b :c :d :e :f] [1 2 3 4 5 6])
(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

for two any size vectors:

```
(defn cycleave [a b] 
  (let [c (max (count a) (count b))] 
    (take (* 2 c) (interleave (cycle a) 
                              (cycle b)))))
```

will give:

```
user => (cycleave [:a :b :c :d :e :f] [1 2 3])
(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 1 :e 2 :f 3)
```

Comment: or if you only care about how long the first sequence is, you can simply do `(defn cycleave [a b] (interleave a (cycle b)))`, which will stop at the `(* 2 (count a))` elements

Comment: if you want only `n` elements back: `(defn cycleave [a b n] (take n (interleave (cycle a) (cycle b))))`